# Serialize and Deserialize 2 Similar XML having different root name and namespaces but same Elements in Single Class

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xml-serialization

I have 2 pieces of XML which are identical with respect of their elements.

The only difference is in the `XMLRoot` name and the namespaces.

I want to serialize them into a single class. Serialization for individual classes works fine, but that's a wrong way to do it.

XML 1 Root:

```
<SYNCCompatibilityTranslations 
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:com/ProductVariety/Compatibility/Translations/v1.0 SYNCCompatibilityTranslations.xsd"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="urn:com/ProductVariety/Compatibility/Translations/v1.0">
```

XML 2 Root:

```
<SyncCompatibilityTranslations 
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ProductVariety/Sync/Compatibility/Translations/v1 SyncCompatibilityTranslations.xsd" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="urn:ProductVariety/Sync/Compatibility/Translations/v1">
```

I cannot use `XMLIgnore`, the difference is the case of XML Root and the namespaces are different.

Thanks,

Comment: Different root element name and different XML namespaces means - those are **different** XML documents. Hence, you **cannot** serialize them with identical code - you will have to have two separate serialization objects - one for each situation

Comment: @marc_s
Isn't there a way, that I ignore the namespaces?
Basically the previous has been upgrade that's why ns are different

Comment: No - XML namespaces are there **for a good reason!** Those make those XML document **different** - and that's the whole point of having namespaces!

Comment: @marc_s, then when user upload any one of the xml how can I determine which on is it?

Comment: Look at the root element's name - that's already a clear distinction.

Comment: @marc_s
Root Elements are always the same :(
just the case of the XMLRoot and namespaces are different in 2 XMl's

Comment: @user3890558 XML is case-sensitive, so they have *different* root element

Comment: @har07 I know it is case sensitive, so Can i make it to lower?